# How to compile .txt file to .resx with VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resgen

Can anyone tell me how to compile a `.txt` file to `.resx` using VS 2010 post build or pre build events?

Answer (score 1):

Use resgen tool from Visual Studio
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccec7sz1.aspx

A good comprehensive link to get started for me was:
http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/10/14/local2.htm?page=1